# Able to remove a file being the other user

Tags: unix, cp

I had copied a file from one directory to my home directory.
Initially, it had permissions and ownerships as (640) and (root:root).
I was still able to delete that file.
Though, it asked for permission.

Any Reasons, as to why this happened??
FYR..

[ia982p@ulpv0143 ~]$ rm cf.ajpcfgmv.conf 
rm: remove write-protected regular file `cf.ajpcfgmv.conf'?y

Comment: Deleting the file modifies the *directory*. Your user owns your home directory.

Comment: I replicated the case under the home directory and when the user is not in the root group the stderr when copying the file (the file is first copied) is "cp: cannot open 'xxx' for reading: Permission denied". I think the issue is about group membership.

Comment: See [why am I able to delete file which belongs to root under a non-root user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75395/why-am-i-able-to-delete-file-which-belongs-to-root-under-a-non-root-user)

Answer (score 0):

The possible explanation is that:

- Your user may be in "root" group, so it has read permission to the file (4) (not as an other user but as a group member)
- Since user has read permission as group member, it can copy the file
- When the user copies a file originally owned by root, the copy is owned by the user
- And then it can be deleted by the user

You can check the groups of your user (when logged in as the user):

```
groups
```

Or alternative check the users in root group:

```
cat /etc/group | grep root
```

And one note: This question should be under [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)